# PHPUnit show errors but not show successful alert

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.8, laravel-unit-test

I use Laravel 5.8 and phphunit version 7.5. When I run PHPUnit with error, show me error but when not has error show me only this line

> PHPUnit 7.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>   My test class:

```
use Tests\TestCase;

class leadTest extends TestCase
{
    public $Array= ['lead_name' => 'Jon','lead_family'=>'Doe'];
    public function test_store()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $this->post('leads', $this->Array());
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('leads', $this->Array);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a syntax error, you should fix it

Comment: You missed a bracket $this->post('leads', $this->Array();

Comment: I edit my post. My problem is not it. Dose not show me success alert.(green alert)

Comment: you are now calling a method that doesn't exist

Comment: how are you running phpunit and where does this class exist?

Comment: phpunit tests\Feature\LeadTest.php --filter=test_store

Comment: you should name the class correctly, and you are also calling an undefined method in your test

Comment: Sorrry try this `phpunit tests\Feature\leadTest.php --filter=test_store`

Answer (score 1):

That is the reason of your error:

```
$this->withoutExceptionHandling();
```

Try without it.

Look also at class name it should be: LeadTest, and the file should be named LeadTest.php

Comment: I test it but not any result

Comment: At the first it's name was LeadTest. I rename it, I think that problem maybe for name of class